# Como usar uma função para verificar os requisitos impostos à uma variável em C++?

Tags: c++, algoritmo

Quero fazer um código para treinar `struct`s. Nesse caso, como o número de carros é 4, quero que a variável escolha esteja limitada no intervalo fechado de 1 a 4 "[1,4]".

Sendo assim, a lógica é:

Enquanto essa variável for menor que 0 ou superior a 4, vai pedir pra digitar de novo. Daí utilizei um `while`.

Tentei usar um `while` sozinho, mas não funcionou, então parti decidir usar uma função, que verifica o valor da variável escolha. Se ela atender aos requisitos, ela retorna 1 (`true`), senão, ela retorna 0 (`false`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct Carros{
    int coresDisp,motores,modelos,ano;
    string nome;
};




bool verificaEscolha(int esc); //prototipando a função




int main(){

    int escolha;

    list <string> cores;
    cores.push_front("Vermelho");
    cores.push_front("Azul");
    cores.push_front("Verde");
    cores.push_front("Amarelo");
    cores.push_front("Preto");
    cores.push_front("Branco");
    cores.push_front("Cinza");

    list <string> motores;
    motores.push_front("2.0");
    motores.push_front("1.5");
    motores.push_front("1.0");

    list <string> modelos;
    modelos.push_front("Completo");
    modelos.push_front("Medio");
    modelos.push_front("Basico");

    list <int> ano;

    for(int i=2005;i<=2020;i++){
        ano.push_front(i);
    }


    Carros car1;
    Carros car2;
    Carros car3;
    Carros car4;

    car1.nome = "Vulcano";
    car2.nome = "Tornado";
    car3.nome = "Furia";
    car4.nome = "Ninjasso";


    cout << "Carros disponiveis: \n\n\n";
    cout << car1.nome << "[1]     " << car2.nome << "[2]     "<< car3.nome<< "[3]     "<< car4.nome<<"[4]     ";

    cout << "\n\n     :               ";
    cin >> escolha;

    verificaEscolha(escolha);

    while(verificaEscolha(escolha)==false){
        cout << "Essa escolha naum eh valida, tente novamente: ";
        cin >> escolha;
        verificaEscolha(escolha);
    }

    return 0;
}

bool verificaEscolha(int esc){
    if(0<esc<=4){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Ignore os outros pedaços do código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução quando algo não funciona é investigar o que está errado, aprender como é o certo, não é complicar mais e causar mais erros ainda.

Seu código tem coisas em excesso, não é sobre programação funcional como classificou a pergunta, e  oque quer realmente é só fazer um `while` simples, só precisa fazer certo, não sei qual era o erro porque não estava na pergunta.

Mudei de lista para vetor porque eu tenho certeza que não deseja uma lista, imagino que nem saiba as implicações de usar uma lista que é mais complexa e menos performática. E organizei o código um pouco.

Alguma coisa me diz que o código tem outros problemas conceituais, mas não posso falar sobre sem entendê-lo mais profundamente.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Carros {
    string nome;
    int coresDisp, motores, modelos, ano;
};

int main() {
    vector<string> cores = { "Vermelho", "Azul", "Verde", "Amarelo", "Preto", "Branco", "Cinza" };
    vector<string> motores = { "2.0", "1.5", "1.0" };
    vector<string> modelos = { "Completo", "Medio", "Basico" };
    vector<int> ano;
    for (int i = 2005; i <= 2020; i++) ano.push_back(i);
    Carros car1 = { "Vulcano" };
    Carros car2 = { "Tornado" };
    Carros car3 = { "Furia" };
    Carros car4 = { "Ninjasso" };
    cout << "Carros disponiveis:\n\n";
    cout << car1.nome << "[1]     " << car2.nome << "[2]     " << car3.nome << "[3]     " << car4.nome << "[4]     ";
    cout << "\n\n     :               ";
    while (true) {
        int escolha = 0;
        cin >> escolha;
        if (escolha > 0 && escolha < 5) break;
        cout << "Essa escolha naum eh valida, tente novamente: ";
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4zLk0t). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/WhileRepeat). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/WhileRepeat.cpp).

Comment: Obrigado. Mas o objetivo era treinar listas mesmo, pq faz parte das video aulas que estou assistindo. Ele não passou esse exercício, mas inventei de fazer.

Comment: Treinar errado você só vai acostumar com o erro, nunca use lista onde ela não é necessária, isso é um erro.